# how to reassemble the processed chunks to a large image

Tags: python, deep-learning, chunks, image-stitching

When using a deep learning network to process a large image, I break it down into smaller chunks for processing. However, when I reassemble the processed chunks, I notice significant differences in color and texture,between the adjacent areas of the chunks, making it challenging to create a coherent final image. How can I address this issue?

I attempted to introduce overlapping sections in the chunks, but the issue still persists

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.